# Armar objeto al cruzar dos objetos

Tags: javascript

tengo dos objetos, el objeto_1 tiene sus keys y como value tiene las keys del objeto_2:

```
objeto_1 {
  nombre: 'name',
  correo: 'email',
  telefono: 'phone',
  genero: 'gender',
  direccion: 'address',
}

objeto_2 {
  name: 'Luis ',
  email: 'lperez@gmail.com',
  phone: '123456',
  gender: 'male',
  address: 'CL 3 # 6 -50',
}
```

Asi que deseo que a partir de eso se cree un nuevo objeto donde se remplace los values del objeto_1 por el value que tiene es key en el objeto_2

```
resultado {
  nombre: 'Luis ',
  correo: 'lperez@gmail.com',
  telefono: '123456',
  genero: 'male',
  direccion: 'CL 3 # 6 -50',
}
```

Comment: Y qué has intentado o investigado? O quieres que lo hagamos todo por ti? Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto puede ser posible con el for, extrayendo el valor y la clave del objeto y armando un objeto nuevo, te dejo el código con el que lo hize:

```js
const objeto_1 = {
      nombre: 'name',
      correo: 'email',
      telefono: 'phone',
      genero: 'gender',
      direccion: 'address',
    }
    
const objeto_2 = {
  name: 'Luis ',
  email: 'lperez@gmail.com',
  phone: '123456',
  gender: 'male',
  address: 'CL 3 # 6 -50',
}


let data = {};

for (const [clave, valor] of Object.entries(objeto_1)) {
     data = {
       ...data,
       [clave]: objeto_2[valor]
     }
  }

console.log(data);
```

Espero te haya servido amigo, saludos

Comment: No hay necesidad que reemplaces el objeto `data` completo en cada iteración, puedes sencillamente asignar la nueva clave y ya: `data[clave] = objeto_2[valor];`

Comment: Es verdad, no se me ocurrió eso, muchas gracias por la observación

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias a los dos por su ayuda